# Android Opencv filter canny

Tags: android, image-processing

[filtered image with canny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVyuX.png)

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr1fm.jpg)
Any advice on how to lessen the noise on the filtered image here. We are using canny edge of opencv in android studio.

```
inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Mat matImage = new Mat ( image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Bitmap myBitmap32 = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, matImage);
Mat gray = new Mat(matImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.cvtColor(matImage, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);
Mat edge = new Mat();
Mat dst = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(gray, edge, 60, 80);
Imgproc.cvtColor(edge, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA,4);
final Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.cols(), dst.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(dst, resultBitmap);
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise erosion as this would remove edges as well. You can try connected-components and remove ones which have too less element per component, but I am afraid that it may remove edges as well. But do try it, before completely discarding it. Also, you can look in Hough Transform, to find pixels which fit closest to a Circle.

Comment: @saurabheights Hough transform woudl only make sense if you could assume that a tree is perfectly round which you can't.

Comment: Have you tried to use hue and saturation info as well or did you just process intensity?

Comment: I agree with you, but I suggested it since it will give you good approximations of where rings will be if such a circle is found. May not work always, but will be a good heuristic for further analysis.